# Python module to read /proc/{pid}

Tags: python, pid, proc, procfs

I want to write a linux metric agent to gather linux metrics in both System Level and Process Level.  I'm pretty like linux command sar and pidstat,  both of them come from sysstat.rpm.

I want my agent have a similar ability to gather metrics like sysstat but with more configurable options. like I want to gather the metrics and send the result to our special monitor system.

The key issue I want to address here is I want to build this tools based on some other tools, like procfs.  procsfs is great since it depends /proc only.  I checked the procfs module, but find this module doesn't provides much Process level metric like pidstat provides.  Do you know any module which is based on /proc and can provide the data like pidstat?

Comment: [psutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) might be a useful starting point for some of what you're trying to do, but if you can be more specific you'll probably get better suggestions

Comment: @AndrewWalker, thanks for suggestion.  I took a look at psutils before, seems it depends on some linux command too much, so I want to search other candidates.